# Log4j2 can't find my config file

Tags: maven, slf4j, log4j2

I'm trying to set up SLF4J to work with Log4J2. But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Here are my POM Dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <log4j.version>2.1</log4j.version>
</properties>

<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using a simple config for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And my log4j2.xml file is located in src/main/resources.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what else to check. I've also tried moving the xml file to the /src directory, but it didn't help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in version 2.1. I rolled back Log4j2 to version 2.0.1 and everything works fine.

Comment: Could you link in the bug please?

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the server you are using to deploy and I was running into this same issue when trying to deploy my web application on Wildfly 8.1 and have my log4j2.xml in the src/main/resources folder.

It's pointed out in [this thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-890) that it's not a log4j2 bug but a bug in the JBoss/Wildfly code.

Quoting Hassan Kalaldeh on the thread:

> I found what is the problem, if you extract log4j-web-2.1.jar and open
>   servlet container Initializer service in file :
>   log4j-web-2.1\META-INF\services\javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
>   you will find this: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
>
> ```
> #
> # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
> # contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
> # this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
> # The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache license, Version 2.0
> # (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
> # the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
> #
> #      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
> #
> # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
> # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
> # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
> # See the license for the specific language governing permissions and
> # limitations under the license.
> # org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer
> ```
>
> I've been reading JBoss deployer source code and I found it always
>   read first row of service file // this line from
>   ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci() String
>   servletContainerInitializerClassName = reader.readLine();
>
> so when I manually edit the service file and just keep the last line
>   (org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer) it
>   works fine now

In anycase, I did revert my log4j2 version to 2.0.2 and it's working as well.